# Android webview - How to use com.android.chrome instead of com.android.webview

Tags: android, android-webview, selenium-chromedriver

This js `=>` syntax below doesn't work on `com.android.webview`:

```
// ECMAscript 6 using arrow functions
var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

It shows error in Android device A (rooted, Marshmallow):

```
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source: file:///xxx.js (16)
```

That `=>` syntax works fine in my LG Nexus 5X and other phones, the logcat shows:

```
WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 58.0.3029.83 (code 302908352)
```

In android device A, it shows:

```
WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119
```

So I suspect the differ webview factory providers make the differs.

I tried to install `com.android.chrome` from play store in device A:

```
130|shell@g9x:/ $ pm list packages -f | grep chrom
package:/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk=com.android.chrome
shell@g9x:/ $
```

But it still same, the logcat still shows `com.android.webview`  instead of `com.android.chrome`. I even tried to pull the `com.android.webview` apk from `/system/app/`, which shows error because of apk not found.

In my code:

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

I heard about [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android) but not sure is it related or not. I also found [this custom webview info](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-android-webview).

So my question is, how to force Android webview use `com.android.chrome` instead of `com.android.webview` ?

**[UPDATE]**

I temporary solved the js `=>` issue by changed it to other syntax alternative, but a bigger problem arose, `com.android.webview` not even able to play html5 video, while html5 video is important part in my task.

Answer (score 0):

you can embed webview into your project try this https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html